# how to read from csv file and store data in sqlite3 using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, sqlite

i have a python class **readCSVintoDB** that read from **csv file** and store data into **sqlite 3  database**.

note :
the csv file includes many fields so i just need 3 of them.

until now i am able to read csv file and stored into **dataframe** using **pandas**. but how to store the dataframe into the database.

## error displayed :

> File "C:\Users\test\Documents\Python_Projects\readCSV_DB.py", line 15,
>   in **init**   self.importCSVintoDB() File
>   "C:\Users\test\Documents\Python_Projects\readCSV_DB.py", line 60, in
>   importCSVintoDB   INSERT INTO rduWeather VALUES (?,?,?,?)''', i)
>
> sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch

when i tried to print i in the for loop  it display the header name **date**

## readCSV_DB :

```
   import sqlite3


    import pandas as pd
    import os

    class readCSVintoDB():

        def __init__(self):
            '''
            self.csvobj = csvOBJ
            self.dbobj = dbOBJ
            '''

            self.importCSVintoDB()

        def importCSVintoDB(self):

            userInput= input("enter the path of the csv file: ")
            csvfile = userInput
            df = pd.read_csv(csvfile,sep=';')

            #print("dataFrame Headers is {0}".format(df.columns))# display the Headers

            dp = (df[['date','temperaturemin','temperaturemax']])
            print(dp)

            '''
            check if DB file exist 
            if no create an empty db file
            '''
            if not(os.path.exists('./rduDB.db')):
                open('./rduDB.db','w').close()

            '''
            connect to the DB and get a connection cursor
            '''
            myConn = sqlite3.connect('./rduDB.db')
            dbCursor = myConn.cursor()

            '''
            Assuming i need to create a table of (Name,FamilyName,age,work)
            '''
            dbCreateTable = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rduWeather 
                               (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
                                  Date varchar(256),
                                   TemperatureMin FLOAT,
                                   TemperatureMax FLOAT)'''

            dbCursor.execute(dbCreateTable)
            myConn.commit()


            '''
            insert data into the database
            '''
            for i in dp:
print(i)
                dbCursor.execute('''
                                  INSERT INTO  rduWeather VALUES (?,?,?,?)''', i)

            #myInsert=dbCursor.execute('''insert into Info ('Name','FA','age','work')
                                         #VALUES('georges','hateh',23,'None')''')
            myConn.commit()

            mySelect=dbCursor.execute('''SELECT * from rduWeather WHERE (id = 10)''')
            print(list(mySelect))
            myConn.close()        



    test1 = readCSVintoDB()
```

Comment: I don't get it. You've clearly done some research to get you this far, what part exactly are you struggling with to go forwards? There's plenty of material about `INSERT` into sqlite3 and parameterised queries. Are you facing a particular issue?

Comment: how to import the retrieved data-frame  into the sqlite3 database ?

Comment: Read a tutorial?

Comment: if i had get the answer from a tutorial i would not ask the question here

Comment: But you haven't tried _anything_ in your question. Please show what you tried and what went wrong. No tutorial is going to give an _exact_ answer to your problem but that doesn't mean you can't try and adapt it to your problem.

Comment: @roganjosh i will edit my question and add what i did  but still not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a single row (e.g: `reg = (...)`) try this function:

```
def write_datarow(conn, cols, reg):
    ''' Create a new entry (reg) into the rduWeather table

        input:  conn (class SQLite connection)
        input:  cols (list)
                Table columns names
        input:  reg (tuple)
                Data to be written as a row
    '''

        sql = 'INSERT INTO rduWeather({}) VALUES({})'.format(', '. join(cols),'?, '*(len(cols)-1)+'?') 
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # Execute the SQL query 
        cur.execute(sql, reg)
        # Confirm  
        conn.commit()
        return
```

But if you had multiple rows `reg = [(...),...,(...)]` then use:

```
def write_datarow(conn, cols, reg):
    ''' Create a new entry (reg) into the rduWeather table

        input:  conn (class SQLite connection)
        input:  cols (list)
                Table columns names
        input:  reg (list of tuples)
                List of rows to be written
    '''

        sql = 'INSERT INTO rduWeather({}) VALUES({})'.format(', '. join(cols),'?, '*(len(cols)-1)+'?') 
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # Execute the SQL query 
        cur.executemany(sql, reg)
        # Confirm  
        conn.commit()
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

After your edition now I saw the problem. You commit the SQL query outside the for-loop.

Code this:

```
for i in dp:
    dbCursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO rduWeather VALUES (?,?,?,?)''', i) 
    myConn.commit()
```

Comment: still not working i will edit my question and add the error that is displayed